# Java String formatting solution

Tags: java, string, formatting, spell-checking

I have a string description of a company, which is nasty written by different users (hand-typed). Here is a example (focus on the dots, spaces, first letters etc..):

> XXXX is a Global menagement consulting,Technology services and
>   outsourcing company, with 257000people serving clients in more than
>   120 countries..   combining unparalleled experience, comprehensive
>   capabilities across all industries and business functions,and
>   extensive research on the worlds most successfull companies, XXXX
>   collaborates with clients to help them become high-performance
>   businesses and governments.,    the company generated net revenues of
>   US$27.9 Billion for the fiscal year ended 31.07.2012..

Now what i want is to format the string to a bit nicer version like this:

> XXXX is a global management consulting, technology services and
>   outsourcing company, with 257,000 people serving clients in more than
>   120 countries. Combining unparalleled experience, comprehensive
>   capabilities across all industries and business functions, and
>   extensive research on the world’s most successful companies, XXXX
>   collaborates with clients to help them become high-performance
>   businesses and governments.  The company generated net revenues of
>   US$27.9 billion for the fiscal year ended Aug. 31, 2012.

My question is: Is there any library with already defined methods which could do all the spelling corrections, unneeded space removal, etc .. ?

So far, I do it be replacing stuff like " ," with ", " and toUpperCase() if the is a "///." in front etc..

```
desc = desc.replace("  ", " ");
desc = desc.replace("..", ".");
desc = desc.replace(" .", ".");
desc = desc.replace(" ,", ", ");
desc = desc.replace(".,", ".");
desc = desc.replace(",.", ".");
desc = desc.replace(", .", ".");
desc = desc.replace("*", "");
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner and better version to do this. Using regex maybe??

Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: The replacements you want to make are quite complex so you will need a parser esp to translate the date format.

Comment: The date format is not a mandatory thing, I'm more focused on the simple corrections like dots, commas, spaces, first letters, spaces between comma/dots etc.. We do have a rule on how to write these things: after a dot there must be a free space before another sentence.. etc..

Comment: Yes, you should try using regexps for this. What have you tried?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I was thinking of it, but i'm not so familiar with complex regexp expressions, I was more hoping for a complete library or set of classes :) But thanks, the more I research the more likely regexp is going to be my only solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I were trying to solve your problem, I would probably read the text 1 `char` at a time, and  format it as you go. For example, in psuedocode...

```
while (has more chars){
    char letter = readChar();
    if (letter == ','){
        // checking for the ',.' combination
        letter = readChar(); 
        if (readChar == '.'){
            // write out a '.' only
            out.print('.');
        }
        else {
            // it wasn't the ',.' combination, so you need to output both characters, whatever they are
            out.print(',');
            out.print(letter);
        }
    }
    else if (another letter you want to filter){
        // etc.
    }
    else {
        // doesn't match any of the filters, so just output the letter
        out.print(letter);
    }
}
```

Basically if you read the text 1 `char` at a time, you can detect any of your chosen formatting problems as you go, and correct them immediately. This provides a performance improvement, as you're only reading over the text string once (not 8 times, like you are currently doing), and allows you to add as many different/complex formatting changes as you want. The downside, however, is that you need to write the logic yourself rather than relying on in-built functions.

Comment: That would just increase the performance a little bit, but true, if you follow the rules, it should be written as joined strings but it's then also less readable code.